# Seção ativa na div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Como eu posso usar o trigger do jquery?
Preciso que a página carregue e esse primeiro "li" já esteja pressionado.

```
            <ul id="quote-popup-tabs">

               <li data-quote-tab-for="consorcio-auto">Automóvel</li>
               <li data-quote-tab-for="consorcio-moto">Moto</li>
               <li data-quote-tab-for="consorcio-casa">Imóvel</li>

            </ul>
```

Comment: Como estás a gerar essa página? tens algum CMS (worpress por exemplo)? qual é o mecanismo para abrir a tab? alguma classe de css envolvida (por exemplo `.selected`)?

Comment: Essa tab é aberta com jQuery? podes colocar o código do jQuery que a abre e o HTML do li que está aberto? um exemplo a funcionar seria o ideal...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso resolve brow:

```
$( '#quote-popup-tabs li:eq(0)' ).click();
```

Se quiser, pode colocar no arquivo functions123.js na linha 502, que fica logo após a função:

```
$( '#quote-popup-tabs li' ).click( function() {...
```